# Is there any difference in creating string object

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between creating a string object like this

```
var txt = new String("Hello World");
```

and this

```
var txt = "Heloo World";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little practical use for String objects as created by new String("foo"). The only advantage a String object has over a primitive string value is that as an object it can store properties:

```
var str = "foo";
str.prop = "bar";
alert(str.prop); // undefined

var str = new String("foo");
str.prop = "bar";
alert(str.prop); // "bar"
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @RUJordan..Agreed and Updated!!

Comment: That's not the only advantage. Passing by reference is another.

Comment: There are differences! See freakish's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

First of all let's bust some myths. String literal is not a syntactic sugar.

```
> var txt = new String("Hello World");
> typeof x
"string"
> var txt2 = "Hello World";
> typeof txt2
"object"
```

As you can see these two things are of different type. Even more: one of them is object and the second is not. This has a practical consequence, like:

```
> new String("Hello World") == new String("Hello World")
false
> "Hello World" == "Hello World"
true
```

Another difference is that primitives are passed by value while objects by reference. This might save some memory if you are passing around lots of big strings. However both objects and literals are immutable so it really isn't a big deal (why would you pass lots of big strings if you're not going to modify them?).

Also you can add attributes to objects while you can't add them to primitive types. But that's not 100% true. You can add an attribute to the prototype of a primitive. Note that both literals and objects have **the same prototype**:

```
> String.prototype.test = 11;
> var x = new String("x");
> x.test;
11
> var y = "x":
> y.test;
11
```

Comment: Who said they were synctic sugar?

Comment: @Bergi Bloodcount (see answers below). Besides: does it matter?

Comment: I don't think one can "bust" myths that don't exist :-)

Answer (score 1):

The String constructor function returns an object of type String. Usually, you want a literal string value, because strictly comparing an object to a literal will always return false.

Comment: I believe this will throw an error in JSLint as well for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

One is a string primitive and the other is a String object.
The advantage of String object over string primitive is that it can store properties

```
var x = "foobar"
x.y = "hello"
console.log(x.hello) /* Undefinded*/

var z = new String("foobar")
z.y = "hello"
console.log(z.y) /* hello*/

typeof x = "string"
typeof z = object.
```

also

```
x==z //true
x===z // false
```

Comment: Please explain why -1

Comment: The guy who -1'd this answer please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing much but beware of this,

```
var s = new String('A');
var s1 = String('A');
var s2 = 'A';


console.log(s === 'A');//fasle -- since type is Object
console.log(s1 === 'A');//true
console.log(s2 === 'A');//true
```

Answer (score 0):

The first returns a String object, the second returns a string.

```
typeof txt; //object
typeof txt2; //string
```

While they may act similar, `txt !== txt2`

Comment: Literal strings "inherit" from `String.prototype` as well.

Comment: that's correct, didn't even notice that

Comment: @freakish: No they don't: `"foo" instanceof String == false`

Comment: @Bergi That's why I used quatation mark. What I've meant is that literals can use methods of `String.prototype`. Besides `"test".__proto__ == String.prototype`.

Comment: @freakish: Property access on primitives is magic and does not count. `String.prototype.isPrototypeOf("") == false`.

Comment: @Bergi It absolutely **does** count. See how people define custom methods like `.startswith` on string literals. And it's not magic, it's just that we don't understand it (probably explained somewhere in ECMAScript specification since it is the same in all JS engines).

Comment: Yes it is explained there, and when you read it you will understand that primitive values have neither properties nor methods…

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = "Heloo World";
```

here 'txt' is a primitive data type. It has no methods, it is nothing more than a pointer to a raw data memory reference, which explains the much faster random access speed.

```
var txt = new String("Hello World");
```

If you use new, you're explicitly stating that you want to create an instance of an Object. Therefore, new String is producing an Object wrapping the String primitive, which means any action on it involves an extra layer of work.

Comment: It's not true: literal string does have methods. Even more: it has the same prototype as `String`. Try adding any method to `String.prototype` and you will see that it is available in literal strings as well. So the only difference is that one is an object and the second is not.

Comment: @freakish: No. Primitive values do not have values. However, when you use a property assessor on a primitive value some magic happens…

Comment: @Bergi What is the difference between "having a method" and "able to access a method" from programmers point of view?

Comment: @freakish: Probably an irrelevant one in practise. However, what is the difference between "having methods" and "able to assign a method"?

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure you'll agree that there is a difference between "I have" and "I can't have more". `"x".test = 1` simply does not work (it should at least throw an exception IMHO, not just silently fail).

Comment: @freakish: Yeah, you're right there is. But the point of this question is that programmers should not be tricked into "*it has properties -> it is an object -> I can add and access custom properties*" by JavaScript's "Everything is an object" paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

The primitive data types are:

- String
- Number
- Boolean

If you using:

```
var txt = "Heloo World";
```

this is primitive type data type `alert(typeof txt);` will give you string type.

In JavaScript all variable can be of object type, for each primitive their is a Object type.

```
var txt = new String("Heloo World");
```

here `typeof` will give you object.

For difference see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd6V7/14/)

```
var str="text"; 
alert(typeof str);     //string

var str2="text";
alert(str === str2);   //true

str = new String("text changed");
alert(typeof str);     //object

var str2 = new String("text changed");
alert(str === str2);   //false
```

Comment: Worth noting: `undefined` and `null` are the other two primitive data types.

Comment: see article, these are Special Data Types.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Not according to ECMAScript specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf `A primitive value is a member of one of the following built-in
types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, and String`

Comment: @freakish thanks, yes they are primitive type, but usually no other language has these data type thats y I say these are special primitive data types. thanks for the links.

Comment: Cool! Let's argue semantics, @ZaheerAhmed! Thank you, @freakish – you beat me to it.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing, really. In the first example you call the constructor of class `String` and put as a parameter the body of the string, where as in the second example it is done automatically at the interpretation phase.

So basically the second is `syntactic sugar`, where as the first isn't.

There is **no** difference in the functionality.

Comment: -1: there are differences in functionality and literal string **is not** a syntactic sugar (otherwise how would you pass a string to the constructor of `String`?). See other people answers.

Comment: A fair point, I should do some research on it.